# How to collect array document values into parent document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

How to perform a similar aggregation to *LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE* and then selecting the columns you want in spark, but with mongodb?

For example convert documents similar to:

```
{
    name: "john",
    surname: "doe",
    arr: [
        {
            itemName: "address",
            itemVal: "2333. Street"
        },{
            itemName: "phone",
            itemVal: "43098685446"
        }
    ]
}
```

into a flat document:

```
{
    name: "john",
    surname: "doe",
    address: "2333. Street",
    phone: "43098685446"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

## MongoDB >= v4.2

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $mergeObjects: [
        "$$ROOT",
        {
          $arrayToObject: {
            $map: {
              input: "$arr",
              in: {
                k: "$$this.itemName",
                v: "$$this.itemVal"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "_id",
      "arr"
    ]
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YF_aFGJbsVr)

## MongoDB >= v3.6

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            $arrayToObject: {
              $map: {
                input: "$arr",
                in: {
                  k: "$$this.itemName",
                  v: "$$this.itemVal"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      arr: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y6SwmS93JPE)

## MongoDB >= v3.4.4

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $arrayToObject: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
          },
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$arr",
              in: {
                k: "$$this.itemName",
                v: "$$this.itemVal"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      arr: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j90jwp4LuHL)